# Android Studio 0.8.2: project using an sdk add-on which provides a jar library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

I am trying to build a SDK add-on so developpers can use our library. I started by using this sample (a jar library add-on containing a system service):

https://github.com/gibsson/basic_sdk_addon
https://github.com/gibsson/BasicService
https://github.com/gibsson/BasicClient

I have followed the instructions from BasicService and BasicClient github pages and successfully created a working image by building both applications with the AOSP (for Android 4.3).
I built the two packages by adding the following to the device.mk file:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    com.gibsson.basic.service.lib \
    com.gibsson.basic.service.lib.xml \
    BasicServiceApp \
    BasicClient
```

This way, everything was build in the image and working.

`End of introduction`

I removed the BasicClient package from the build process and I am trying to bring this client in Android Studio, with the SDK, as would Android developpers do (they don't have access to the AOSP)

The basic_sdk_addon was successfuly created by following the instructions and using this command:

```
AOSP$ make PRODUCT-basic_sdk_addon-sdk_addon
```

I installed the Add-on in Android Studio using a User-defined repo.  In the BasicClient project, I had to manually add the .jar file to the app/libs folder and click "Add as library" in order to compile BasicClient properly.

When trying to run/debug the BasicClient from AndroidStudio, I get the following error (from logcat, it's more detailed):

```
I/ActivityManager( 2544): Start proc com.gibsson.basic.client for activity com.gibsson.basic.client/.BasicActivity: pid=3311 uid=10044 gids={50044, 1015, 1028}
W/dalvikvm( 3311): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/gibsson/basic/client/BasicActivity;(0x4213e238):0x40030000 ref [Lcom/gibsson/basic/service/lib/BasicManager;] Lcom/gibsson/basic/service/lib/BasicManager;(0x4213e238):0x4001d000
W/dalvikvm( 3311): (Lcom/gibsson/basic/client/BasicActivity; had used a different Lcom/gibsson/basic/service/lib/BasicManager; during pre-verification)
D/AndroidRuntime( 3311): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 3311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41891700)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at com.gibsson.basic.client.BasicActivity.<init>(BasicActivity.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3311):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 2544):   Force finishing activity com.gibsson.basic.client/.BasicActivity
```

I understand that there is a mismatch between the BasicManager dex file found and what it expects. I verified if the tools used where the same version between the AOSP and Android Studio: both use the same JDK (1.6.0.45) and the same compile version (18).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working: it seems that importing the BasicService Eclipse project modified the Dependencies scope drop down menu (in Project Structure). I can now choose **Provided** instead of **Compile**, and the application works perfectly.
When creating a new project from scratch, I only had the following choices: Compile, Runtime.

So I've looked at the differences between the two projects and the `build.gradle` file was the only one that was changed: `compile` was replaced by `provided`.

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/com.orthogone.canvas.service.lib.jar')
}
```

There seems to be a bug in the UI, as the Dependencies Dialog doesn't provide this choice even with the build.gradle modification.

Another important note: the AndroidManifest.xml must contain the `<uses-library>` information in the `<appliation>` section:

```
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.gibsson.basic.service.lib"
        android:required="true" />
```

Comment: This bug/feature is fixed in the current release of Android Studio (v1.2.2). It was fixed between 0.8.2 and 1.0.0.